# How to make a single Mongo connection in Spark Rdd with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I want to read mongo data in Rdd mapToParis , here is the code :

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("app");
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
JavaRDD<String> lines = jsc.textFile("./input_user_log/*");  // read data from file

JavaPairRDD<String, UserLogBean> pairs = lines.mapToPair(s -> {
        // connect to mongo
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("mongoHost", 27017);
        MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("DbName");
        MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("CollectionName");

        UserLogBean bean = new UserLogBean();
        bean.id = coll.find()......;   // read mongo data
        return new Tuple2(bean.getId(), bean);
    }
);
```

But Mongo connections are too many.

If I put ...

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("mongoHost", 27017);
MongoDatabase db = mongo.getDatabase("DbName");
MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("CollectionName");
```

... outside, it will cause:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

Could I make a single Mongo connection?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you pass into `mapToPair` must be `Serializable` since Spark may choose to serialize it and ship it elsewhere for execution.

The class: `MongoClient` does not implement `Serializable` so you cannot ask Spark to pass that around.

This explain the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

You will need to create the `MongoClient` instance *inside* the lambda you pass into `mapToPair`.

If you are concerned about creating too many connections to your Mongo server then you can configure each `MongoClient` instance with a specific connection pool size as follows:

```
MongoClientOptions clientOptions = MongoClientOptions.builder()
    // choose the number of connections per Mongo client here
    .connectionsPerHost(1)
    .build();
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("mongoHost", 27017), clientOptions);
```

Comment: thanks for replying. But the MongoClientOptions does not seem to work , still has many connections

Comment: How are you measuring the connections? And are you sure that the excess/unwanted connecitons are definitely coming from the Spark Rdd instances? Have you tried to trace these connection to their client processes? e.g. `db.currentOp().inprog.forEach(function(x) { print(x.client) })`